# Pythonic way of extending base class

Tags: python, class, pandas

I am trying to create a pandas Dataframe like class with some added constructors:

```
class ExtendedDataFrame(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ExtendedDataFrame, self).__init__()   # without this I get a pandas error

    @classmethod    
    def contructor1(cls, filename):
        "Create DataFrame from file"
        df = pd.read_csv(filename) # returns a DataFrame
        df.__class__ = cls
        return df

    # more methods extending Dataframe ...
```

So now I am able to do:

```
ExtendedDataFrame.constructor1('table_xx.txt')    # returns an ExtendedDataFrame instance
```

What I would like is to be able to get an instance of my Table class in this way:

```
ExtendedDataFrame('table_xx.txt')
```

What is the recommended way to do this?

In other words, I am trying to make an `ExtendedDataFrame` class but some pandas's methods like `read_csv` return a `DataFrame`, and I want to have an `ExtendedDataFrame` returned.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why not just say that `Table = pd.read_csv` and use that?

Comment: I plan to use pd.read_csv or pd.read_fwf depending on the arguments(filename type) passed at construction time, I also plan to extend the class with other methods.

Comment: If it is just about filename distinction, do this externally or define a simple function that returns a dataframe. What do you need the `Table` class for other than making a distinction between input data formats?

Comment: So you've got two things then: 1) Extend DataFrame with new DataFrame-y methods, and 2) A factory function to pre-populate the DataFrame... Umm... I wouldn't get so hung up about calling `Table()`... Just have a smart `DataFrame.smart_load()` and have that internally call private methods to load the data instead of messing about with the `__init__` and any confusion that may occur later in getting DataFrame and your extended DataFrame to interact nicely together...

Comment: @JonClements, If I do 1) how can I have a module from where I can import my Table/ExtendedDataFrame class? and 2) could you clarify this?

Comment: check out [this github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4271), there has been some discussion re subclassing dataframes etc. in the past, hopefully it'll be easier in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use argument expansion in your `__init__` method, investigate the arguments provided and if you find one string argument, then perform the `Table.constructor1('string')` internally.

On the other hand, looking at your question more closely, I am wondering what you want to achieve here. So far, your `constructor1` classmethod does not make sense. What kind of functionality do you want to implement so that `df = pd.read_csv(...)` is not enough for you?

Comment: could you clarify 'perform the Table.constructor1('string') internally'?

Comment: It is just an example, in practice I plan to use read_csv or read_fwf depending on the arguments passed to the constructor, plus add some method specific to my problem

Comment: Within the init method of your class, i.e. in the internals of your class, so that it is not part of the interface.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke I'm wondering if this is just boiling down to the fact that `read_csv` will return a `DataFrame` while the OP wants it to return `ExtendedDataFrame`...

Comment: @JonClements, thats exactly what I want, apparently I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke, within init I can not create a new instance.